# Executing if/else conditional inside a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to execute a if/else conditional inside a JS 'for' loop. Specifically, this is  what I'm  told to do: [image: http://i.imgur.com/lA1mRGp.jpg]

Here is my code

```
var numSheep = 4;
var monthsToPrint = 12;
for (var monthNumber = 1; monthNumber <= monthsToPrint; monthNumber++) {
  if (numSheep < 10000) {
    numSheep *= 4;
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
  } else {
    numSheep *= 4;
    var number = numSheep / 2;
    var newNum = numSheep - number;
    console.log("Removing " + number + " sheep from the population. Phew!");
    console.log("There will be " + newNum + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
  }
}
```

Everytime I submit this code I get this error from codeschool, *"You're calling console.log the correct number of times, but not logging the correct messages. Are you diving the numSheep by 2 whenever there are more than 10000."*

P.S: It's challenge no. 5 of JavaScript Road Trip Part 2 on codeschool. If you need to log into codeschool and see for yourself, this link should give a 48 hour access: http://go.codeschool.com/eO1V6A

Comment: @eosterberg Hi, that doesn't change anything unfortunately. It prints out the same things as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got everything correct

- First of all as @eosterberg mentioned in a comment the text says "for any month the population is above 10,000"
- Secondly you need to save the number of sheep you have left; `numSheep = numSheep/2`, the sheep you sent away is right now the same but store that in a variable, sentSheep.
- Thirdly the text says; "The rate at which the staying population is grows, however, will stay the same(x4)" this means that the population that stays only grows(at least what we know) => you should put `numSheep *= 4;` after the calculations and before the `console.log`'s

And the actual code would look like;

```
var numSheep = 4;
var monthsToPrint = 12;
for (var monthNumber = 1; monthNumber <= monthsToPrint; monthNumber++) {
  if (numSheep <= 10000) {
    numSheep *= 4;
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
  } else {
    numSheep = numSheep / 2;
    var sentSheep = numSheep;
    numSheep *= 4;
    console.log("Removing " + sentSheep + " sheep from the population. Phew!");
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help ;) Do you understand everything @user973282, so you learned something from it?

Comment: I hope I understand. The first  mistake  I  made was, I  didn't store  the new value of sheeps after removing  half off it. I was just calculating it and as, I didn't save any new data the calculations were wrong when we started to remove sheeps!! Also, as the growth should be calculated after we take away sheeps, the  numSheep *= 4; should be after we remove the required no. of  sheeps. Did I get it right? :)

Comment: Yeah pretty much, you missed the `<=10000` thing otherwise it looks good. Good luck with learning JS ;)